# How to get the tree before the last pull (HEAD@{1})

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

I'm trying to get the list of changes after a pull. Thinking on using `LibGit2Sharp.Diff.Compare`

I can get the HEAD tree by `repo.Head.Tip.Tree` where `repo` is `LibGit2Sharp.Repository`.

What about the previous HEAD? `HEAD@{1}`?

Comment: I found this to work, is this the best way? `repo.Lookup<Commit>("HEAD@{1}").Tree`

Comment: What do the docs say? Are you aware that commits aren’t diffs?

Comment: @evolutionxbox can u please elaborate?

Comment: The previous head you mentioned would point to the commit where the head was before pulling assuming that the head had not been moved since. As for my diff comment, a commit is a snapshot of the entire repo and is not a diff. Unless the library you’re using outputs a diff you may have to calculate it yourself.

Comment: @evolutionxbox thank you, yes, I'm using a library that performs such action (This question is tagged and aimed specifically to it https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp). As for your commit vs diff comment, correct, a commit is not a diff.